# Customizing Filter.js to Grab and Output HTML Based on JSON ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm using https://github.com/jiren/filter.js for a product filter, and I've succeeded in getting it to talk with a custom JSON file and attributes, but I need to use a find and replace function on the ID attribute (1, 2, 3, 4, etc) to replace the ID number with custom HTML containing a PHP block with the same ID, replacing that ID with the "itemCode" in the JSON file.

Jiren's working pagination example: http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/pagination.html

We're using that, except we want to take it to next level and modify it (probably with jQuery) to do something it doesn't do by default (recursively replace the ID from the JSON with a block of HTML/PHP and then replace that same ID number with the itemCode from the JSON).

Put more succinctly: Filter.js populates the results using the paginator, grabbing the data from JSON. I'd like it to then replace `<dt>id</dt>` with a block of HTML which includes a line of PHP that grabs the corresponding itemCode from the JSON.

For example, having edited the template provided --

```
`<script id="product-template" type="text/html">
        <div class="col-md-10 product">
          <div class="thumbnail">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4><%= _fid %>. <%= name %></h4>
            <div class="detail">
              <dl>
                <dt>modelName</dt>
                <dd><%= modelName %></dd>
                <dt>caseTypes</dt>
                <dd><%= caseTypes %></dt>
                <dt>power</dt>
                <dd><%= power %></dd>
                        <dt>battery</dt>
                <dd><%= battery %></dd>
              </dl>
            </div>
            <div class="detail">
              <dl>
                <dt>id</dt>
                <dd><%= id %></dd>
              </dl>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </script>`
```

-- which it calls for with every iteration, I'd like to replace the `<dt>id</dt>` (which outputs as a 1, 2, 3, 4, etc) -- in other words, replacing the '1' -- with a section of HTML (that happens to contain PHP). The first entry being '1' should call the line `<td class="info"><?php item('1'); echo $urlMode1; ?></td>` which ought to be replaced by the "itemCode" we have sharing an entry with the id ('1').

Out of JSON:

```
`
[
{ "itemCode": "DSVUC1000",
"modelName": "DogStar",
"caseTypes":"Voltron",
"power": "Unlimited",
"battery":"Car",
"id": 1
},
{ "itemCode": "DSOWD150",
"modelName": "DogStar",
"caseTypes":"Optimus",
"power": "Wood",
"battery":"Duragizer",
"id": 144
}
]
`
```

Filter.js populates the results using the paginator. Ideally, it would then replace `<dt>id</dt>` with a block of HTML which includes a line of PHP that grabs the corresponding itemCode from the JSON.

What sort of approach do you recommend to accomplish this?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Thanks! If anyone has any feedback, that would be great. Where is the best place to stick the working example? It uses a lot of custom and separate files. We have an example but it's on the server. We're using this: http://jiren.github.io/filter.js/pagination.html and it's working, except that we want to take it to next level and modify it (probably with jQuery) to do something it doesn't do by default (recursively replace the ID from the JSON with a block of HTML/PHP and then replace that same ID number with the itemCode from the JSON). Thanks!